# Warning assignment from incompatible pointer type while assigning to another parameter

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-warnings

In  code i'm getting this warning  while compiling.
I tried to fix this my i'm unable to solve this issue.

```
  static uint8_t tx_data;

 int *recvdata2,*recvdata;
 recvdata= str2int(tx_data); //warning assignment from incompatible pointer type
recvdata2=(uint8_t*)&recvdata
```

str2int is a function to convert the string to integer.

```
   int str2int(char *str)
{
    int res=0;
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    res=(res)*10+str[i]-'0';
    return res;
}
```

I'm a noobie to this. Please help me to fix this issue.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which part of the warning message is unclear?

Comment: `tx_data` is a `uint8_t` but you are passing it into `str2int` as if it's a `char*` (see the prototype of `str2int`). `recvdata` is an `int*` but you are assigning the return value of `str2int` -which is an `int`- to it.

Comment: Can you determine wheter the comment by Motun or the answer by Kiran are more to the point?

Comment: @EricPostpischil None. OP should know, understand and focus on the message emitted by the compiler. SO is not a place to dump error/ warning message and seek the solution.

Comment: @EricPostpischil No one denied that there's a fix, it just needs more involvement from OP to find the fix, before posting (dumping) the non-mcve code and a very google-able warning message as a title. **Regarding the rude part:** I did not intend to be rude, apologies if I appeared such. Intention was to point the OP to the right direction and encourage to read and re-read the error message.

Comment: @EricPostpischil **(1)** already voted on the question. **(2)** As I mentioned before, the intention was not to be rude, and I'll keep that in mind for future. **(3)** With all due respect, **kindness** is subjective.

Comment: @EricPostpischil does passing parameter constitutes as "assignment" error/ warnings?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: You are correct, I was focusing on the error I noticed first in the code, rather than the error pointed out by the error message. Nonetheless, the same things apply: Understanding it requires knowledge of the type of the right hand side, knowledge of the type of the left hand side, knowledge of the constraints of assignment operations, what it means for types to be compatible or incompatible. **It is a very complicated matter.** Just because you learned it years ago and it has become subconsciously automatic for you does not mean it is easy or evident from the message.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The last sentence actually makes a lot of sense..maybe I need to broaden my views...thanks for the note and conversation..

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are trying to assign `int` to `int *`
You see `recvdata` is pointer to `int`.

Modify as below.

```
 int *recvdata2, recvdata;
 recvdata = str2int(tx_data);
 recvdata2 = &recvdata
```

Comment: That only solved one of the 2 bugs though. Basically the answer is "use the same types as the function expects".

Comment: @Lundin Yes I agree.

Answer (score 0):

- You know that you have a function `int str2int(char *str)`.
- Thus when calling that function, you need to ensure that you pass a `char*` as parameter and take an `int` as result type.
- Upon getting compiler errors, you check if you use the correct types. Turns out that you pass `uint8_t` instead of `char*` and use `int*` for the return type instead of `int`.
- Furthermore, it is obvious that the function expects the caller to allocate the data, so the `char*` needs to point at an allocated array.

Summary: you can't program by trial & error. Check the function first, ensure that you know what it expects, then write the calling code.